# reference property of one project file in another project file

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

I have one project file, "LibraryProject.csproj":

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <Company>Acme, Inc</Company>
    <Copyright>(C) 2023</Copyright>
    <Product>My Project</Product>
    <MajorVersion>0</MajorVersion>
    <MinorVersion>1</MinorVersion>
    <PatchVersion>0</PatchVersion>
    <VersionPrefix>$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(PatchVersion)</VersionPrefix>
    <Version>$(VersionPrefix)</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion>$(VersionPrefix)</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>$(VersionPrefix)</FileVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Is it possible to reference a property from this project file in another project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ProjectProperty>$(LibraryProject.VersionPrefix)</ProjectProperty>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="LibraryProject.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I'm not really sure what to try; I'm not sure how to build a reference to another project file in this way.  I want to be able to version the output of one project based on the version from another project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can reference or add dependency to another proyect visit:

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2022

You have two projects: Project_A and Project_B, you want to include Project_B in Project_A:

- In VS open Project_A You add a project reference
- Find the location of Project_B and select it
- Verify that Project_A now has a project dependency indicating that
  it is Project_B

Project_B has a public class:

```
namespace Project_B
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int idem { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

To reference the Employee class in Project_A:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();

int _Idemp = employee.idemp;

string _name = employee.name;
```

Try it and you will see that it is very simple

Comment: I have already added a project reference as seen in the example above.  I need to know how to reference a property declared in the referenced project file.